# Xcode7でPhaseの順序の入れ替え方法

Tags: xcode

Xcode7でターゲットのPhaseの順序を変更しようとしています。
しかし移動させたいPhaseをドラッグしても他のPhaseの間に移動することが出来ません。
Xcode6でも移動できないことがありましたがまれに移動が成功することがありました。
ですがXcode7では全く移動できなくなってしまいました。
project.pbxprojのPBXNativeTargetをエディタで編集する方法がありますが、できればGUIで操作したいです。
どのようにすればXcode7でPhaseを移動できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phaseをドラッグして間に移動するというのが高い確率で失敗するので、順番を入れ替えたい場合は、入れ替えたいもの以外を一番下に順に移動させていく、という方法でやるのがいいです。

一番下にドラッグする操作は、コツをつかめば成功します。

Comment: たしかに一番下には移動しますね。ありがとうございます。